# reject this binary in new itunes connect UI

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

With new itunes connect UI, I can't find the "reject this binary" option. I received an error "checksum validation failed" for my upload. Please help me to reject this binary.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think this is a temporary issue from iTunes connect if you wish to remove you currunt build from App Store that appear as a waiting for review follow the following steps.

with the new iTunes connect you if your app is waiting for Review state you can see this type of information in side your app Details.

[image]

When you click on remove this version from review.

**UPDATE**

When your app is rejected or you are trying to new app upload do following steps:

- First You have to upload a binary again from `Xcode or Application Loader`. There is appear you last setup Build with Version number select it and upload again.
- Then, wait for some processing time  and open your iTunes Connect account. You can check your uploaded build in **Prerelease** tab
- After processing finish In Build section Click on **+** button and select a correct binary that you have uploaded and save. Here is actual [Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/UploadingBinariesforanApp.html).
- After that you may click on **Submit for Review** Button. And it may take some time for uploading on iTunes again

Comment: My app is "waiting for upload" state. I can see build uploaded in pre-release option. I visited the apple forum and there are more people facing this issue https://devforums.apple.com/thread/243714

Comment: My app is now "waiting for review state". It works with above suggestion.

Comment: Apple appears to have "improved" the design of this page as of 9/7/2014 -_- I'm not seeing a way to reject it anymore, and the iOS app trick doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: how can I reject when the status is `Prepare for Submission`

Comment: @NitinHi.. my app is rejected from iTunes Connect, Can you please help me to how can i reject or upload new binary when my app status is rejected in new UI, should i need to download XCode 6?

Comment: @AnandGautam check my update answer. Hope that working for you

Comment: Thanks for your answer@NitinGohel. It means according to the new iTunes Connect UI, we dont need to manage application status, simply should upload new binary from XCode. So should i need to change the build and version in XCode in case if app is already rejected from iTunes Connect. Thanks

Comment: I think if app is rejected then you got the last build appear on choose option. so i dont think you need to change version if app is rejected. but if you are update your version then you need to change in you xcode as well. In short if there in application Loader drop-down appear build with last version that rejected so you no need to change in xcode.

Comment: This no longer appears to work. When I click the blue build version (as shown in your picture) it leads me to a new "Build Details" screen with no way to reject the binary.

Comment: Use the iOS app. We managed to reject a binary yesterday using the iOS itunes connect app. So if the reject button still isn't on the website try the app.

Comment: @EthanAllen: This answer is about how to "reject" a submitted build from submission. It does not remove the build from the list of uploaded builds. You cannot remove a build from that list. You simply upload a new build and select a new build to submit.

Comment: @NitinGohel i click on "Remove this version from review". Next what i need to do to upload my app to AppStore

Comment: no need to do after reject this binary simply uplado you new build with correction but make sure that version in xcode must be same. and same process for upload.

Comment: I just learned that there are bunch thing on the app details page that *don't show up in browsers other than Safari*   when I opened iTunes Connect in Safari, I was able to easily reject my binary without issue.

Comment: I couldn't find anything like the "info" button, but when I went back and forth in my browser history it eventually showed up after some time. Phew, that was really irritating.

Comment: Like @auco the blue box wasn't showing for me. I edited one piece of info (switched from automatic release to manual release) and that made the box show again.

Comment: @rob5408 toggling the manual/automatic release radio buttons didn't show the info box. Any other bright suggestions?

Comment: @adib Did you save after you toggled? The save button shows up in the top right.

Comment: @rob5408 yeah I'd saved it and it didn't show. But I waited overnight and then the blue bar just appeared so I managed to reject my app and replace it with another binary. Strange? Yeah. Probably typical behavior for an in-house "enterprise" app, but unfortunately there's no "IT support" that an enterprise app usually comes with.

Comment: @adib Sadly it's typical for Apple + Internet

Comment: Six months later, it seems that the issue hasn't been fixed yet. I had to submit app to validation, refresh the page once or twice before the blue bar appears and reject the binary.

Comment: @Skoua yes that taking some time from iTunes Connect side after upload binary and it's being waiting for review state. but the reject option not appear Sudan that taking few mints or hour not fix.

Answer (score 13):

Right now the only way I've found is to reject it from the iTunes Connect Mobile application.

EDIT: You will need to change the version number anyway or just the build number.

Comment: How do you do this? I can't reject any apps from the iOS iTunes Connect app.

Comment: When you tap on the Products tab, any application with any Pending or In Review status will show the "Reject this Binary" message in red. http://cl.ly/image/2Y241q2n1y17

Comment: Be sure to update your ITC app to the most recent version first!

Comment: I have the latest app version on iOS8. This button is not there.

Comment: I wish I could sue apple. I don't see "remove this version from review" option

Comment: This worked for me, too. It's ridiculous Apple would release a new Web ITC with such a simple feature missing.

Comment: There's no "Reject this binary" button for me, the first thing I see is  "status waiting for review".

Answer (score 8):

NOTE: This answer pertains to rejecting/replacing a binary on the WEB INTERFACE for iTuens Connect, not the ITC app.

After uploading a new build - with a higher BUILD number [but the same version number] - I figured out that if you mouse-over the icon for your selected build [on the versions tab] you are given a "-" minus sign. When you tap that you can replace the current build with the newer updated build.

Comment: Thanks, this worked in the end, but I could only make it work by manually unhiding the (-) button first (inspect element, locate the a href, then add `display:inline-block!important`). It seems that the new build is set successfully.

Comment: I also had to do what @mvds stated.  Odd.  Thanks for this info though.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the version number to something different. You will now see a 'remove this version from review' link at the top of itunes.

First upload a new binary with the new version number.  Then you can click on the previous version and you will have the option to 'reject binary' and you can click the above link 'removing version from review'.

Comment: this is the correct answer! you don't need to reject the binary anymore - just add a higher BUILD number (same version) and you can upload. then choose that build and submit.

Comment: They've made it easier.  After submitting there is a link at the top that says 'remove this version from review' which will allow you to reject.

Answer (score 2):

I just spent two hours trying to reject a binary, the option which should be just under the "Versions" tab simply wasn't there, even though other users have posted screenshots of it and it's described in the Apple docs.

The solution was to reset Safari completely, log back into iTunes Connect, and lo and behold, the option was now available.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

When you hover your mouse you could see the option button, which you can update

Answer (score 1):

For the latest version of itunesconnect.apple.com, it is very hard to find the reject binary (actually I don't find it at all).

You can download the '**[itunes connect app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/itunes-connect/id376771144?mt=8)**', login and go to the specific version you want to reject. 'Reject This Binary' is marked as red, you can easily find.

[image]

Comment: Absurd that this was the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is an **Apple** issue and occurring following the new iTunes Connect UI release last night (2014-09-05).

I have experienced the same with a new app release. It has never been uploaded. The first upload failed due to the internet connection (adding just in case that is relevant). All uploads after (on completely unlocked connection) shows the error `'Redundant Binary Upload'`.

Currently speaking to Apple Itunes connect support, will provide an update.

UPDATE - 15:23  GMT
Apparently no issue at present. They are emailing me steps to take, and send further information back for them to investigate. Will update again

UPDATE - 2014-09-06
After speaking to Apple again yesterday they escalated the issue and had someone look into this.

Now I can select the build against the app in ITunes Connect and there is a new button **Submit for Review** now showing up, well played Apple! :-|

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,

and I can confirm that I could re-upload a binary by:

1. Submit the app for review temporarily
2. Then **rejecting the app via the iOS iTunes Connect app**

Comment: I have tried this today but didn't work. Uploading a new binary still ends up with "Redundant binary upload"

Comment: @ZoltanMagyar I have the same exact issue, I cannot get rid of the build, if you find a solution let me know. Will do the same

Comment: I'm trying http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767777/how-to-remove-a-build-from-itunes-connect ATM. I.e. accepting that it is a change of philosophy and increasing the build number (not the version). :)

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded binary and overlooked that in iOS8 method to register for remote notifications changed, since I couldn't find way to reject this binary I uploaded new binary with updated method and increased build version.

Gues what? They approved first build...

EDIT: I think that this might help: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/UploadingBinariesforanApp.html

On versions tab we can delete or select one of builds uploaded before, and one selected will be review by Apple

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'reject this binary' option at new itunesconnect, because you can upload more then one builds for version. Furthermore you have chance to cancel review by selecting 'remove this version from review'. And then you can select another build to submit for review.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can increase the build version in Xcode and upload a new build. This will solve problems with duplicate binaries.

Comment: That solution actually works. 09.11.2014. Otherwise other uploads will have status "Uploaded" and will not process further.

Comment: It does accomplish the end goal of being able to upload a new binary. However, it appears that there is no way to properly "reject" and remove a binary as before. It looks like all uploads are permanent and they have to have different (and I assume ascending) build numbers.

Comment: How/Where do you change the build number in xcode ?