# How to delete app Build in New iTunes Connect Site?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, app-store-connect, itunes

I want to upload my app's new version on [iTunes connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/), but I can't submit it as I mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25681089/waiting-for-upload-status-issue-in-new-itune-connect-site).

Now I want to delete uploaded build and upload new build with save version, but I get an error as shown in the screenshot.
[image: here]

[**Find Solution Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699404/new-itunes-user-interface-unable-to-find-ready-to-upload-binary)

you can't delete old uploaded build.you have to upload new build with new build(+1) version.

Comment: Your developer certificate is different. That's a problem. You should use correct developer certificate which was used for your previous version uploads

Comment: my developer certificate is right, but i want transfer my app in to different account that why this warning is displayed...But it don't care boy it' i need solution for first error...

Comment: Did you change the plist version number?

Comment: possible duplicate of [New itunes user interface unable to find "ready to upload binary"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699404/new-itunes-user-interface-unable-to-find-ready-to-upload-binary)

Comment: Hannes Sverrisson,i added your answer in my question

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You can't delete old uploaded build: you have to upload new build with a new **build version** (== *Bundle version in plist*).

For example, if your current build version is 1.3, archive & upload a new build with an incremented build version like 1.3.1:

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear(er), the build number is your 'Bundle version'. This is what you should increment. Users do not see this, this is for your own reference. I had a Bundle version of 2.0.2 and 'incremented' it to 2.0.21 to get it submitted. If I need to submit a further build I'll make it 2.0.22, 2.0.23 etc.  My 'Bundle versions string, short' remains 2.0.2 - this is what users see.

Comment: Hi, I did this and the Build line of my iTunes Connect App still shows the old build and upload date, even after the new one finished processing.

Comment: as i'm said you can't delete it,you have to add new build and attach new build with you submission.

Comment: This is additional info which is reference to other answer. How can we 'remove the version from review' [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25680614/2641380) from new iTunes site. We may sometimes not see the line mentioned in the answer. After iTunes logout/login with some time gap, we will be able to see the line 'remove this version from review' on iTunes.

Comment: This is "incorrect". You very rarely want to change your Build, i.e. the version number in App Store. You want to change the Version (called "train" in the lackluster error message), which can be any number. This will result in the "version x for train y" to be different and the error message to go away, and lets you keep the app version number you intended.

Apple must be trying for some new record in fing their systems up and making them convoluted beyond despair. I'd give you a list of the things that used to work in XCode and now don't, but it'd be long and tedious to read.

Comment: In other words, Version in the picture is your CFBundleShortVersionString.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot delete a Build from Itunes Connect. Your project info file contains two attributes for referencing the Build version of your app, i.e., **Bundle version** and **Bundle versions string, short**. Usually both attributes have the same value (1.0.3) but you can upload to the Itunes Connect multiple Builds for the same version of the app just changing the second value.

So, you create a new version of the app in Itunes Connect (version 1.0.3) and set in your ***NewProject*-Info.plist**:

- Bundle version: 1.0.3.
- Bundle versions string, short: 1.0.4.

Archive and upload.

Once Itunes Connect processes the new Build, it will appear in the **Pre-Releases** section and you will be able to select it for the 1.0.3 version and send it for review.

Comment: You have to increment CFBundleVersion, not the short version string.

Answer (score 6):

The new version of the iTunes Connect App for iOS devices does not seem to have the "Reject Build" capability as did previous versions of the app and the iTunes Connect Portal. You cannot reject or delete builds uploaded to iTunes Connect in the latest versions (Dec 2014).

**The solution is to just upload a new build. However for iTunes Connect to accept the new build, you must first increment an internally visible build number before recreating the archive.
The number to increment is labeled "Build" or "Bundle Version" depending on where you look in the Xcode interface. A change in one location obviously is reflected in the others.**

Here are the locations where you can change the Build/Bundle Version number:

General > "Build: 1.0.1"

-or-

Info > "Bundle Version: 1.0.1"

-or-

Info.plist > "Bundle Version: 1.0.1"

Once the number is changed, re-archive the build and re-submit it to iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure that there's a way to delete a build, but updating the Build Number and re-submitting worked for me.

[ERROR ITMS-9000: "Redundant Binary Upload. There already exists a binary upload with build version '1.0' for train '1.0'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680604/error-itms-9000-redundant-binary-upload-there-already-exists-a-binary-upload)

Answer (score 2):

Edit: You just can't. I imagine you will have one chance per year to clean up builds like they do with registered devices, or maybe they just plan to keep them there forever.

Check Apple's response from this thread:
 [How to remove a build from itunes connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767777/how-to-remove-a-build-from-itunes-connect)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to delete a build just like Mark Philip said.
I am using Xamarin. I fixed my problem by doing this in Xamarin: 
project -> options -> IOS Application -> build