# New itunes user interface unable to find "ready to upload binary"

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I am trying to update my app to iTunes connect but it seems it has **NEW INTERFACE** and 'ready to upload binary' button is missing.

I app is free and dont have any In-App Purchase, Newstand  and game center. I have added **"
What's New in This Version**" section with new features. Also while saving the page it is not showing me any error.

Can some one please help me to figure out when is the button to change status of app to "**Ready to upload binary**"??? I have checked everything but unable to find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You press `save`. Then upload the binary. Then select it `+` and `save` -> `Submit for Review`. You don´t need to set it ready to upload binary any more.

---

You can upload more than one binary by increasing the number in **Build** (Select the Target, then Xcode -> General -> Build, see picture) by adding **.1**, i.e. the version was `3.75` -> `3.75.1`, but the Build version is still `3.75`.

[image: Showing where to set the Build Version in XCode]

Then the new binary is uploaded and may be selected for review. In the picture below you may see the old and the new binary listed in iTunesConnect.
[image: Showing list of binaries in iTunesConnect]

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I have been able to upload the build successfully.

Comment: How can I select a build version for review? I can not see any options to do that

Comment: @Tom, just wait 15 min and it will appear

Comment: Thanks, but I waited for 2 hours, and nothing.

Comment: @Tom Then upload again.

Comment: After waiting for some more hours, it became enabled! :) Thanks all for your help!

Comment: @Tom I am glad it worked out, but this seems to happen sometimes. Usually its 10 min. for me.

Comment: @HannesSverrisson
Please cam you explain what does this warning near build mean?