# How to remove build from Pre-Release in new itunesconnet?

Tags: ios, ipad, upload, app-store-connect

I have added a version 1.0 in prerelease section in new iTunes. Now i need to upload same version(1.0). but i am getting error that version 1.0 is still there. I have already rejected binary but 1.0 has not removed from Pre-Release.

So i am thinking that i can upload version 1.0 only if i remove it from Pre-Release section. But there are not any way to remove build from pre-release section.

I have refered

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/UploadingBinariesforanApp.html

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible to delete an updated build from the prerelease section.

You can submit a new build with the same version number but a different build number as explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25699845/428981

Hope that helps!

Comment: This makes me sad. I hope Apple fixes all the annoying things soon.

Comment: I too am sad. Incrementing the build number allowed me to submit as well.

Comment: But how can I set which build number version should be reviewed by Apple?

Comment: @Tom in iTunes Connect for that app, go down to the "Build" section and you can (-) the build selected and (+) add a build from all the different build numbers you've archived and uploaded. At the very top of the page, right under the icon and title you can click on "Prerelease" to see the builds that have been uploaded. If one is still "pending" you'll have to wait a bit before you can select it

Comment: Thanks, very kind from you, but the possibility is missing from there, I triple checked it. There are my 2 builds there, in the list I can see only  upload date, internal/external state. Both are inactive.Also there is installations column, it is empty for both.

Comment: Thanks my friends, I had to wait some more time, after three hours I could do it. :)

Comment: Yes, it takes a while for uploaded builds to become available for submission on iTunes Connect.  Sometimes it processes quickly (a few minutes) other times longer  :-(

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible right now. Apple are keen to get feedback on the interface, so as we could do this in the original Testflight and many of us clearly want this functionality, they may add this ability in the future. With any luck..