# iOS 8 removing build from review in iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ios8

I just uploaded a new build to the iTunesConnect in preparation for the iOS 8 release. The app status is "Waiting For Review". However, I want to reject the uploaded binary and upload a new one.

According to [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW34.) (section: Removing a Build from Review) there should be a message with the link to remove a build from review.

Expected Message:
"You can only edit all information while your version is waiting for review. To submit a new build, you must remove this version from review." Click "remove this version from review"

My issue is I don't see this link in iTunesConnect.(Snapshot)
[image]

Is anyone else facing this issue?

Comment: I have the exact same problem!! WTH is wrong with Apple.

Comment: See [here][1] it's fixed now.. The remove message is back.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799874/how-to-reject-binary-from-itunes-connect-after-redesign-12-09-2014/25800118?iemail=1&noredirect=1#25800118

Comment: Thanks @Markive. The message with the remove link is back indeed.

Comment: As of December 12th the issues still stands. I've re-submitted 4 new versions with same version numbers & different builds and with different versions & different builds. NO REVOKE LINK. I waited 3 hours and still no link. Next morning link is back. I know this isn't an answer to the problem, but just letting everyone know that the issue is still existing.

Answer (score 33):

I've had the problem and waited up to a day, putting everything behind schedule, but the "remove version from review" still didn't appear.

Obviously this is a bug on the iTunesConnect server side, so I found a way to **force it to show** I hope will help others.  It might happen sporadically (second time it has for me), so hopefully this will help others in the future.

> *Firstly, to reiterate other messages, this only work when the status is "waiting for review" - if you cannot upload you binary etc, it will
>   be due to other problems such as updating your build version.*

---

**To force the "remove version from review" message to show:**

This uses **Chrome's** developer tools (same premise applies to firefox etc).

- From the iTunes connect page for the app version you wish to reject, press F12 to open the developers tools.
- Select the source for the page and press CTRL-F to open the find dialog.
- Search for "remove version".
- This will show the enclosing DIV of the dialog.  Find the main parent DIV, which should look something like this:

`<div class="ng-modal ng-isolate-scope ng-hide" ng-show="show"...`

- It's then a simple matter of removing/renaming the ng-hide class - this will immediately popup the dialog !

Comment: This worked for me as well. But I loaded iTunesConnect from Safari, because the loading is super slow in Chrome. Instead of searching for 'remove version' through the source code of the page, I used 'Inspect element' and searched for it there. Found it, removed 'ng-hide' and magic happened. Thanks!

Comment: It totally worked! Thanks a lot. The class to search for is "deleteIcon". One of them is the delete button that appears in the builds section. Once you find it, remove "ng-hide" and you're good to go.

Comment: popup is showed up immediately, but remove button didn't effect anything, any suggestion?

Comment: Same experience as @aykutt here.  I got the popup to appear, and clicking the "Remove" button got a response (the button made a "loading" animation and the page refreshed), but the "Waiting on Review" status was unchanged.  I tried four times, same result.

Comment: I was able to reject the binary through the iTunesConnect mobile app...real annoying

Comment: This is not the correct way to do this, this is hack and not consistent! Scroll down for real solution!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue.   I changed some text in the description to enable the SAVE button.   Saved, and then on refresh the Expected Message: "You can only edit all information while your version is waiting for review. To submit a new build, you must remove this version from review." Click "remove this version from review" appeared and I was able to reject the binary.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't see it it could be a bug of the site, but the link to remove the build from review is placed in the home of the version you are currently sending for review!

From itunes: Select your app -> AppStore Tab -> Select current version

[image: How to]

Answer (score 3):

You can download an iTunes Connect app from the App Store and reject the binary by it.

Comment: Tried iTunes Connect App and unfortunately that doesn't work in that the control to reject the binary is not available.

Answer (score 0):

This has also been a known bug with iTunes Connect.

If the link to reject the binary does not show up in 15 minutes, you can submit a new build with a new build number and submit that instead.

Comment: How do you do that, if you can't remove the current version from review?

Answer (score 0):

There is another work around for the same. Your project info file contains two attributes for referencing the Build version of your app, i.e., Bundle version and Bundle versions string, short. Usually both attributes have the same value (1.0.7) but you can upload to the Itunes Connect multiple Builds for the same version of the app just changing the second value.

So, you create a new version of the app in Itunes Connect (version 1.0.8) and set in your NewProject-Info.plist:

Bundle version: 1.0.7.
Bundle versions string, short: 1.0.8.
Archive and upload.

Once Itunes Connect processes the new Build, it will appear in the Pre-Releases section and you will be able to select it for the 1.0.3 version and send it for review.

Answer (score 0):

Simply increment your build number and xcode will allow you to upload it. Once uploaded you can select any of the builds you want in iTunesconnect.

[image]

Comment: This is not what the user asked!

Answer (score -1):

This might help

[New itunes user interface unable to find "ready to upload binary"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699404/new-itunes-user-interface-unable-to-find-ready-to-upload-binary/25699845#25699845)

It looks like you can't remove the binary (please let me know if you find a way) but can just increase the build number by .1  as a work around.

Answer (score -1):

Use Safari. It shows up in highlight at the top "Remove this build from waiting for review." (or something similar"

Answer (score -2):

If **status:Ready for sale** you can only submit a new version

If **status:waiting for review** you can remove the build from the Build section of the itunes connect and click save . Staus will change to "**Prepare for Submission**".

Afterwards, you can proceed with your final build .

Hope it helps. Thanks

[image]

Comment: This is theory. In practice, their system is so crappy that the remove build option does no appear. My app is since yesterday on waiting for review and there is no link.