# How to reject binary from iTunes Connect after redesign (12/09/2014)?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I need to reject my binary so I can re-upload. This was always quite a hidden option on iTunes connect. Now with the re-design, I've looked everywhere and can't find it.

According to Apple's own docs:

> To remove your build from review Open the App Details page for the app, as described in [To open the App Details page for an app](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/CreatingiTunesConnectRecord.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH13-SW21).
>
> On Versions, above the app's metadata, this message appears: "You can
>   only edit all information while your version is waiting for review. To
>   submit a new build, you must remove this version from review." Click
>   "remove this version from review"

[See page here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW34)

However, I do not see this dialog. It's as though it's been replaced by the App Preview Video section..

Am I missing something? How can I reject it, to re-upload?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799181/ios-8-removing-build-from-review-in-itunesconnect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I am having this link above version Information section, Try to Refresh or Relogin and see,

[image]

Comment: I think Apple must have been bombarded with support requests and fixed it quick smart! Thanks for letting me know..

Comment: I wish I could sue apple. I don't see "remove this version from review" option

Answer (score 1):

As of 11-Sept-2014 - there seems to be no way to do this.  Yesterday the message in hemantchittora's solution was possible and so was rejecting the binary from the ITC iOS app, but today neither of those seem possible.  I have submitted this exact question to Apple Support.

Update:  After waiting a few hours for the build to process the message in hemantchittora's post finally did appear.  So it seems you can't reject a build right away but only after it finishes processing.  When uploading a new build you have to increase the build number (but not the version number)

Comment: Do you know how long I need to wait to reject the binary? It's been over 4 hours and I still dont see the button !

Comment: How long you should wait?

Comment: If it doesn't appear after 4 hours or so I would suspect something else is going wrong.  You may want to logout and log back into iTunes Connect.