# Remove iOS app when the status is waiting for review

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I submitted an updated iOS app. I want to submit another build instead of that.[image]

I removed the binary from review and i deleted the build. No way to upload the same version build again at the time of validation its showing same build already exists.I want to replace this update with another build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change the build.
Let's say your build is 2.0 , change it to 2.01 , archive this and upload again.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Hope this will help.
There is an option to Cancel the binary in iTunes. Select that and upload the new binary. 
Open Itunes account.....
Select Manage Your Applications....
Click on the application....
Click on View details....
Click on Binary Details.... 
Select 'Reject Binary'....

Comment: You can refer this.......https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html

Comment: i deleted the binary but in itunesconnect no chance to remove the build completely, the same version build could not archive again

Comment: You can not completely remove the build u were going to upload but yes you can upload another build having the same version which was cancelled and +1, for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have submitted an app for review, you have an option to remove the app which is being reviewed. Just navigate to "App Store" in iTunesConnect you can see the message and link to remove your app. You can change the build number and upload a new build to AppStore again using Xcode or Application loader.

Answer (score 0):

The "Remove this version from review" link is on the same page from where you have submitted the app: AppStore Connect > App Store > iOS App > [Your app version]

But **it will appear only after a few minutes after your submission**, so don't be desperate if you can't find it anywhere. Just wait a few mins and reload the page.

[image]

In some rare cases it might not appear after a long time. If that's the case, check answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25799181/2650588)