# Testflight itunes connect status rejected (external testers)

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

I am transfering my testflight account to the integrated testflight itunes connect.

By lack of knowledge, the first build that I made was version 1.0 . After that, I change the version to 0.0.1 , submitted the app and it got rejected :

[image]

As I didn't make any significant changes in the code, I suspect that it must be because of the build number.

My questions are: 
1- I would like to reset all this to start from build 0.0.1 . Is this possible to do without creating a different app?

2- If not, is this build number related with the release version? (When I submit to the appstore)

Comment: Just call the first version 1.0.1. Why would that be a big deal?

Comment: I am still in beta versions, I dont want to release it to the appstore as 1.0.x (x>1)

Comment: why does it matter if your beta app has a version number of 1.0.x?  Do you want to follow some rule you learnt in coding school or keep your app name?

Comment: Accept the fact that you made a tiny mistake that honestly no one will ever notice.  And if your anal about that stuff just don't make the mistake next time.

Comment: I am not concerned about the betar version. I am concerned about the first version released to the appstore. Is it okay to submit a first version >1.0.0?

Comment: Will it let you do 1.0.0.1?  If so you can still make your first release to the app store as 1.0.1.  My point is the same.  That no end user will care or even notice if your first version to the app store is 1.0.1.  OR even 100.0.1.  In fact they might feel like they're getting a more solid build.  But 99% of your downloaders won't even look at the version number.  You're worrying about something that only a coder would even notice.  It will not effect your profitability.

Comment: I know that. Just wanted to keep it "as I learned in school"

Comment: In fact.. one of my buddies (also) has an app company.  They're trying to get vc and all that.  (where I'm just totally indie).  Their first version out was 1.0 but they didn't do a real launch then.  Only a soft launch.  Their first version that they told anyone about (on the app store) was 1.1.  And within a few months they're already on 2.0.

Comment: I get that you want to do it right.  It's why I didn't post any of this as an answer.  I just don't want to see you lose your app name in an attempt to fix it.

If it's a super big deal to you write the apple iTunes team and ask them if they can reset your current version to 0.9.  MAYBE they can.  Probably they won't though.

Comment: I will follow your advice. I don't want to lose the name. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

1. No, it's impossible.
   [How to delete app Build in New iTunes Connect Site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683441/how-to-delete-app-build-in-new-itunes-connect-site)
2. Yes, this version must match your app version in iTunes connect.
   [Which iOS app version/build number(s) MUST be incremented upon App Store release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125159/which-ios-app-version-build-numbers-must-be-incremented-upon-app-store-release)

So, the easiest way - remove this app and create new.

Comment: Will I be able to register the app with the same name?

Comment: @jonypz, don't know for sure. You better try.

Comment: Terrible advice. DO NOT delete and try to reregister your app.  Very likely you won't get the same name.  Just go with a 1.0.1 version number.  End users won't care at all about that.  Heck, call it 100.0.  No end user will ever care.  But if you can't get your app name back you might care a lot.

Comment: @badweasel, you always able to **change** app name while not in **review**. jonypz's app not even tested yet. So nothing to worry about.

Comment: Right.. you can change the name when not in review.  But not to anything.  Only to something not already taken.  Doesn't mean you can get your old name back after you remove it.  I know specifically of someone who had to call their app "AppName 2" after deleting the app and trying to re add it because it said that "AppName" was taken.  And if this guy doesn't want his app to be 1.0.1 he def won't want the actual name to have to be different.

Comment: @badweasel, I'm not sure, in case your app never was published to App Store. I mean do they hold app name before it got to App Store?
You right too. In jonypz place, I would have give up and continue with 1.0.1.

Comment: Yes they hold app names before they are released. I recently lost an app name I had reserved to NBC because I was infringing on their trademark.

Comment: @badweasel, 1) change current app draft name, 2) create another with desired name, 3) profit

Comment: Good luck!  The one time it won't work is the time it matters.  And b - 1 and 2 have nothing to do with profit. Staring with a version 2.0 might actually be more profitable than starting with 1.0. ;)