# Unable to submit my app to app store from itunesconnect.apple.com

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I am trying to submit my app to app store. So in the xcode, I selected product, archive
Then validate, and Upload to App Store. I got a message upload was successful.
So now when I go to itunesconnect.apple.com
Under build it say “Submit your builds using xcode 5.1.1 or later or Application Loader 3.0 or later”

If in itunesconnect.apple.com I click “Submit for Review” I get error “There are one or more errors on the page.” Which points me to Build. So where did that upload go?

If I try to upload it again from xcode I get this message
Can someone help me as what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete app Build in New iTunes Connect Site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683441/how-to-delete-app-build-in-new-itunes-connect-site)

Comment: see Same problem as above as above image.

Answer (score 1):

it means the already the same version/build No available in iTunes connect , just change the build no to 1.0 to  2 or 1.1, and then upload new build to appstore, it works

[image]

Comment: Actually, I checked in iTunes connect under "Prerelease" tab and seeing the following: Upload Date: Sept 22,2015, version:1.0, Status:Processing. Should I wait since it been over 12 hours or should I increase the version and submit again? Is it normal for processing to take this long or I did something wrong? I assuming if it made it this far, I must have done everything correct? –  borna 28 mins ago

Comment: @borna -- in waiting for review time you can change anything , so you can change in now or later as your wish , when change this the apple take the re consideration for check this

Answer (score 1):

The error is thrown because you have already uploaded the build with same build number earlier.

If you have already uploaded the build and want to submit that, wait for about 30-45 mins.  It may get appear sooner than that. Itunes takes time to update. There will be `+` sign next to `Build` in build section. Click that and choose the appropriate build and then submit it for review.

If you want to submit the same version again, change the `Build` number in your Xcode in Project Target--> General--> Build.

Or if you are submitting the new version, change the `Version` number in your Xcode in Project Target--> General--> Version.

Do things accordingly.

Comment: Rumin, you said "There will be + sign next to Build in build section|"
No, I don't see the + sign next to the build.That was the reason I tried to submit again to see what happened.Also my first submit was 10 hours ago, I am hoping it shouldn't  take this long, to appears in iTunes connect.

Comment: Then try submitting it again by changing the build number. Increment it by 1. Or else, check your email account that is associated with your itunes. Apple might have notified you about the build if it contained any error. At times, build gets submitted successfully, but due to some error, it does not actually, which will be notified to you via email from apple.

Answer (score 0):

iTunes Connect won't allow, what it sees as, a duplicate version of the app, so bump the version tags to `1.01` and `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Increase your build number to 2 and try to upload it again.

As itunesconnect won't allow to upload same binary build for same version again. If you want than there should be already build in your itunes with the build number 1 for your current version (i.e. 1.0).

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with iTunes Connect (specifically with the Build section) using browsers other than Safari. If you aren't already, try accessing iTunes Connect with Safari.