# How to remove a build from itunes connect?

Tags: app-store-connect

I want to delete one of my app builds from new itunes connect site.
But I couldn't find a delete/remove button.
Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: You can't. I had to developer reject couple of times and I had 6 of these there. I selected one and then submittted for approval. There is no way to remove "non-needed" ones from this list

Comment: I just asked apple about this. I'll let you know when they answer.

Comment: My problem is, I keep getting e-mails saying my "binary has issues" (I mistakenly submitted one with same build number as previous app version). But the app appears a s "In Review" and can't reject the version (button not available!)

Comment: @EFE did they answer from Apple?

Comment: Arrghh. So unlike old TF, now I *have* to create an identifier, then *have* to create an AppStore Provisioning file (no more wildcards), then *have* to create an itunes app, then *have* to upload with their manual Application Loader tool, then *have* to increment the build number each time I upload.

Comment: @SpaceDog You don't have to upload a new version number. Only the build number has to be incremented.

Comment: Now you can delete anything https://stackoverflow.com/a/52682672/5306470

Comment: @EFE any reply from Apple?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Time has changed, you can now remove (expire) TestFlight Builds as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43975385/2122253) but you still **cannot delete the build**.

**OLD:**

I asked apple and here is their answer:

> I understand you would like to remove a build from iTunes Connect as
>   shown in your screenshot.
>
> Please be advised this is expected behavior as you can remove a build
>   from being the current build but you cannot delete it from iTunes
>   Connect. For more information, please refer to the iTunes Connect
>   Developer Guide:
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/

So i just can't.

Comment: If you upload there may be problems with incorrect keychains / provisioning profiles so a delete build function would be nice. But I suppose I should learn to validate the build first before uploading.

Comment: Found the workaround here by updating build version no - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680604/error-itms-9000-redundant-binary-upload-there-already-exists-a-binary-upload

Answer (score 86):

## Wait! You can expire a build actually! :)

**After 2017 Solution:**

## Still same at 2024

1. From the homepage, click My Apps, select your app.
2. Click the **TestFlight tab**.
3. In the sidebar, below Builds, click the platform (iOS or tvOS).
4. In the table on the right, in the Build column, click the app icon or build string for the build that is missing compliance information.

5.Click Expire Build.

[image: how to Expire Build App store iTunes Connect]

*Ta-da!* Build expired at the App Store Connect.

## Means:

- [Internal testers](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev34ab4e57b) and [external testers](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deved4d898a5) will no longer be able to install this build.
- You can remove a build from being the current build
- But, You **cannot delete it from [App Store Connect (iTunes Connect)](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/)**

### Required roles

- [Account Holder](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev1d7b9bccf)
- [Admin](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devf3ef59c83)
- [App Manager](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev26fb1aeb8)

*See [Role permissions](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deve5f9a89d7).*

For more information [please visit](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev82e9b4303).

Comment: That works! Thanks. Just keep in mind that you have to log-in as agent or and admin.

Comment: I think this will only expire build for testing in Testflight only; will not delete build from itunes connect server (AppStore section). You can still submit these builds to appstore. But, orignal questioner is asking about how to delete builds from itunes connect server so that it will not be shown in  "Add Build" section builds list.

I think Apple don't allow to delete build from iTunes Connect server.

Comment: I can confirm that this solution DOES NOT work. It removes the build from the TestFlight dashboard, but the build still exist and you cannot submit a new build to review until the last one finishes the process...

Comment: I finally managed to submit a new build in Testflight. While changing only the build number Itunes Connect keeps complaining about "You can’t submit a build for testing if another build is already in review", changing also the version number allowed me to add a new version for review. I don't know if this is related with expiring previous builds or not.

Comment: I don't even have a button like that. I'm pretty sure it used to exist but now it's not there.

Comment: @gusutafu please talk with your account Agent, you need to be a minimum admin right for taking this action.

Comment: Ah I see, makes sense. I was really scratching my head about this one, thanks!

Comment: That's not removing the build at all, because I still have access to that artifact from Build section in Prepare for submission menu:

Answer (score 35):

I had this problem. I'll share my ride on the learning curve.

First, I couldn't find how to reject the binary but remembered seeing it earlier today in the iTunesConnect App. So using the App I rejected the binary.

If you "mouse over" the rejected binary under the "Build" section you'll notice that a red circle icon with a - (i.e. a delete button) appears.
Tap on this and then hit the save button at the top of the screen. Submitted binary is now gone.

You should now get all the notifications for the app being in state "Prepare for Upload" (email, App notification etc).

Xcode organiser was still giving me "Redundant Binary". 
After a bit of research I now understand the difference between "Version" & "Build".
Version is what iTunes displays and the user sees. Build is just the internal tracking number.
I had both at 2.3.0, I changed build to 2.3.0.1 and re-Archive.
Now it validates and I can upload the new binary and re-submit.
Hope that helps others!

Comment: Changing the 4th octet (or rather adding a 4th octet) doesn't work.  it now yells at you stating that is an invalid # as it must only contain 3 digits.  This is getting excessively annoying how Apple keeps braking iTunes connect like this.

Comment: This only happens when I have not submitted. How do I resubmit?

Comment: Wow, not even the accepted answer but was the woking solution for us.

Answer (score 8):

Choose the build

The answer is that you Mouse over the icon for your build and at the end of the line you'll see a little colored minus in a circle. This removes the build and you can now click on the + sign and choose a new build for submitting.

It is an unbelievably complicated web page with tricks and gizmos to do the thing you want. I'm sure Steve never saw this page or tried to use it.

Surely it's better practice to design the screen so that you can see the options all the time, not to have the screen change depending on whether you have an app in review or not!

Comment: I had two builds in that situation and the weird thing is, it worked for the first one but not for the second one.

Answer (score 5):

As I understand the new iTunesConnect philosophy :

- you can upload some multiple "eligible" builds to iTunesConnect int the "pre release" tab
- let some other testers test a specific build, via TestFlight (and declared as iTunesConnect users)
- when you come to a stable version, select the correct build version, from the "Versions" tab to submit to the AppStore, the usual way.

To me, you can have like 150 build for a pre release, it doesn't matter.

Comment: I wouldn't mind it if I could add testers to OS X Apps, but you can't, only iOS

Comment: I have v1.1.1 and v1.1.3 in TF. Is it possible to completely remove 1.1.3 and then upload v1.1.2? Please confirm.

Comment: Yes it should be possible with new rules availables in Testflight... the build number should only be different.

Answer (score 3):

## in itunes connect:

AppStore >> iosAPP >> Build (scroll down)

click the red icon as seen in the picture

[image: delete build]

Comment: The red icon is only showed on mouse over. You need to put the mouse over it.

Comment: This saved my sanity. The UX on appstoreconnect is truly insane. If you need to change the build you are submitting, this is the route to achieve it. Apple does seem to love the concept of "hidden functionality".

Comment: Mouse over what area? I am still not able to get the "red delete icon". Kindly advice

Comment: just put the mouse where the red circle is suppose to be

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

In our case, deletion was not possible due to already having an app that we were in pre-release. The fix was not to delete but rather to edit each section, including version number, that needed to change for the new candidate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to remove and resubmit the app on the ItuneConnect currently.

I also faced the same trouble as you guys, but I realize something:

It needs to submit the current build to change the status from "ready to review" to "waiting for review" status

Then, click to kind "remove this build for submitting the new one"

-> App's status will change the "Developer rejected",

-> Then you can able to resubmit the new build normally. (I attacked the demonstration)

1: ---
[image]

2: ---

[image]

3: ---

[image]

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Dang this is hard. Here is what I did  to reject/delete/replace my ios build before it was released. The app was approved how ever I found found a bug I wanted to fix before releasing

1. I set release to "manual" and saved
2. I tried to create and app release
3. got an error message something like "you can only have one release at a time"
4. where the save button was there was not an option to cancel release
5. the version of the app is not marked "developer rejected" with a red dot

To replace the bad build I did the following

1. if you click on the "+ version or platform" to create a new version you will not be be able to create a new iOS version
2. you need to upload a new build
3. in your rejected app, select the new build
4. save
5. submit for review

Answer (score 0):

For ios apps On the v1.0.10 App screen (rejected version) you moved down the form to the version number and clicked on the little red button next to it.
This allowed me to select v1.0.11 (the new corrected version) - I then edited the App screen changing the version number to v1.0.11 and completed the "what new notes". Then pressed the re-submit button, which it appeared to accept.
Then at 13.34 I got an email from Apple (referencing the original version v1.0.10) stating "Prepare for Upload" followed by another email at 13.37 referring to v1.0.11 (the new version) saying "Waiting For Review".

I used this link https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/app-store-how-to-delete-an-earlier-build.110763/

Answer (score 0):

Feb 2022 Correct answer. I spent an hour trying to figure out how to remove the OLD Build which had been rejected, and replace it with a newer one.

[image]

1. Remove the App from review. You cannot remove an old build if the App is still "In Review or a Rejected state".
2. AFTER STEP 1, Mouse Over/Hover over the row with the old build and a RED BUTTON appears on the right side of the row.
3. Click RED (-) Delete button.
4. After deletion the familiar UI that allows you to select a new build appears and you can select it.

Damn it Apple!! If it ain't broke, DONT FIX IT.