# Changing bundle Identifier in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, bundle-identifier

For now I have an app in `iTunes Connect`. That app has its own bundle identifier and apriopriate provisioning profiles, App Identifier, and so on... In `iTunes Connect` I have some prereleases versions there.

Now I would like to change my bundle identifier for my app. What happens in iTunes Connect? **Does it change anything in my iTunesConnect?** I would like to avoid creating new app there.

Answer (score 0):

**Can I change my bundle identifier in iTunes Connect?**

I've just found out that I **cannot** change my Bundle ID once I upload my first build:

[image]

**So, is there a way to remove my builds?**

I made some research, and according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25849014/2725435) (answer from Apple) it **is not possible**:-)