# Remove old builds from testing in Testflight

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

Recently I have noticed, that Apple's TestFlight app provides possibility to install older builds of application (application is during internal testing).

It is actually a nice feature, but is there any chance to remove some build that I don't want anybody to install anymore?

My case: I found some bug in app, that causes problems on a server-side - app simply overrides data. Problem in app is already solved in build X, but TestFlight still allow user to install build X-1.

I've tried:

- found this option
- stop & start testing
- change app version (from 0.1 to 0.2) but builds of version 0.1 are still available - probably until expiration date (60 days from
  upload)

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/25849014/4210332

Comment: Thanks, but I actually don't need/want to remove build from iTunesConnect, but from TestFlight - and by remove I mean stop testing (remove from client TestFlight app). Question is from days, where there was only one build available to install. Also in accepted answer there is a part: `you can remove a build from being the current build` - it's close to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove a build from itunes connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767777/how-to-remove-a-build-from-itunes-connect)

Comment: @MaxMacLeod It does, however, the question was asked for iTunesConnect and not a TestFlight. Also, the answer was updated 3 years after I asked the above one.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Under TestFlight builds (ios),
If you have multiple builds, select the bad one.
Next expire the build, currently on the righthand side of the screen.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there was no such option when I asked a question, but that's exactly what I asked for. Thanks!

Comment: Strangely iOS uses its own terminology than the rest of the world which makes it hard to deal with Apple. I would expect "delete" build instead of "expire". Expire in my opinion is to keep the build but not able to install for testers. Delete is to delete the build completely.

Comment: Weird, I have a build for 3.0 of my app.  That build has expired entirely awhile ago but still is in the TestFlight tab.  There is no other way to remove it it seems.  Unless it's not meant to be removed at all.

It's bothersome because the 3.0 version was an accident upload and not needed.  We're still on 2.6.X version release.  Would like to get rid of the 3.X build group entirely on TestFlight.

Comment: Did you find a solution @ScottN? I did that 4.x.x even we are on 1.05 :(

Comment: @T.Y.Kucuk unfortunately no.  It's still there and won't go away.

Comment: I don’t see this option. Does apple remove this?

Answer (score 7):

This does not solve the problem.  The problem is that if you have "Manage Version and Build Number" checked in XCode Distribute App, it will create a new build number for you if you forgot to update it before you Archived.  Consequently, builds can be uploaded to TestFlight and assigned a new number which you may not want - such as when XCode Distribute seems to have shown an error but actually has uploaded the build anyway.

In our case, we need to keep the build numbers in sync with our Android builds using Flutter.  Yes, you can expire a build, but that build *stays there and you can't delete it*!!!  Is there ANY way to actually DELETE the build, not merely expire it???

Comment: same issue. so frustrating. every time a new annoyance by apple

Answer (score 0):

This is related to only if you had an issue to resolve from **Prior submission**:

1. Go to the **App Review** => **Resolve** page and delete the old build.
2. Once done, check the **IOS App** section for the updated status, which should now be **Developer Rejected**.
3. Navigate to the **Developer Rejected** page, and there you can **NOW** remove the old build by hovering over it and using the red icon that appears.