# Impossible to Reject Binary in new iTunesConnect UI

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

We submitted our binary, but discovered that there was an error. I uploaded a new binary from XCode6 and it shows up in the Prerelease Tab of iTunesConnect. It has a higher build number (#708) as opposed to the "waiting for review" version (#704):

[image]

I can't figure out how to use one of the new binaries instead of the old binary. According to the Apple documentation, there should be a notification at the top of the screen (see the "To remove your build from review": https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW34)

I don't have this notification, nor can I find a reject binary button anywhere.

Other people can't figure out how to reject either, but none of the tricks here worked for me: [reject this binary in new itunes connect UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678723/reject-this-binary-in-new-itunes-connect-ui)

Even on the mobile app, or in the Versions tab, there is no reject binary button. I've tried restarting Safari, using Chrome, etc.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not actually a programming question. Try http://apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Almo, if you read [the FAQ pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), it pretty clearly states that **tools** also used by software developers are on topic, too.  iTunes Connect is such a tool.  It's much more a **programmer** tool than a general **Apple** tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have already selected a binary, it shows up in the Build window. Roll your mouse over the version/build number and a small - sign in a red circle appears. Click the - sign. This deletes that binary from iTunes connect.

Next you get the screen telling you to "Click + to add a build..." Click the message or the + sign next to build.

[image]

If you have submitted more than one binary, you will be left with a list of the submitted binaries. Select the radio button for the one you want to appear on the App Store, then click Done.

[image]

The other binaries are still there, so you can go back and select one of them if you like. If you really want to get rid of them completely, select them first, then reject them by clicking the - sign (as described above) until only the binary you want to keep is still there.

Comment: Thanks, but the red delete button never appears for me. I roll my mouse over the icon and/or the link to the name, and nothing happens. Here's a screenshot, FWIW: http://cl.ly/image/180i1X0Z013z

Comment: Did you submit another binary? I had several there already. It may not want to delete the selected binary unless there is an alternative.

Comment: Yes, per my original post, I have both build #704 (Waiting For Review) and #706 in my "Prerelease" tab. I'll update with screenshots to help.

Comment: Roll your mouse over the binary. You should see a - minus sign. But your app should not be in review for that to happen.

Comment: As I said above, and posted a screenshot, I tried rolling my mouse over it. There is no minus sign. I've tried 2 computers and 4 browsers now.

Comment: @ZaneClaes in the screenshot I see you have some text selected. If you don't see the minus sign it means your app may be in review. If so, you need to reject it before changing the binary.

Comment: Zane, it beats me. I get the - sign when I roll the mouse over the version number. I'm using Safari 7.0.6 and OS/X 10.9.5, FWIW. iTunes Connect is acting weird in other ways, though. I can't upload screen shots a the moment, even after trying to upload one that I just deleted. I always get the message "One or more screenshots have the wrong aspect ratio." They don't, and like I said, I've even tried resubmitting screen shots that were accepted earlier in the day. Perhaps iTunes Connect is having trouble in general at the moment.

Comment: @Mike I feel you! I've just uploaded a few minutes ago two binaries and each of them show a much smaller file size than the one reported by Xcode... Could please check if your binaries are the same size as reported in Organizer? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the file size shown is definitely much small in iTunes Connect. I'm seeing 987 KB for the file size there, but 53.7 MB for the xcarchive file in the Finder.

Comment: Weird! I submitted a developer support request to Apple. Good to know I'm not the only one.

Comment: @Mike contact iTunes Connect Support! I've just received an e-mail from them requesting more information regarding the issue. Select in the contact form the topic: iTunes Connect Upload or General Error Help. If we're many with the issue, they'll start fixing it.

Comment: I just checked here after submitting to iTunes Connect Support. :) Hope they fix this soon...

Comment: @Mike sorry for the off-topic but your iOS App rocks!!! I've just checked your website and apps... absolutely awesome work!

Comment: Thanks! Also, for what it's worth, some of the issues disappeared yesterday afternoon. I'm now able to upload screen shots for the new screen sizes, which was broken. Has anyone tried manipulating the binaries? Perhaps that is fixed, too.

Comment: I wonder why this is the accepted answer... No solution there that I can see!

Answer (score 0):

The new iTunes Connect is very temperamental when it comes to showing binaries in the Build tab. I submitted three new versions with no problems, and the new build showed up within a couple of minutes. On another app it took several hours for the new build to show up. It's slightly insane I must admit. I guess Tim Cook's phrase "Everything is great" does not apply to iTunes Connect.

You can only reject your build when it has been associated with a new version - and you can only do that if your build is showing up to be selected in the Build tab. If you haven't associated a build with your new version yet, simply submit a new one and wait for it to show up there so you can select it. There's no need to delete unused submissions, you just don't associate them with a new app version.

Looks like every build you submit shows up instantly in the Prereleases section (where we don't actually need them) but the system can take a long time to show those under Build in your new version. This is especially true if you submit more than one build before associating ine with your new version (at lest it was with my problematic app).

I suggest you give it 24 hours and if you still can't see your build get in touch with folks at iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that you can NOT reject a binary until you have at least another build with the same version (and a different build number) uploaded.

I used XCode/Organizer to submit another build (2.5.7.1) and then I was able to click a MINUS button next to the current build (2.5.7) in an app version where the status is "Waiting for Review" and select the new build. Both builds were for version 2.5.7 and appeared under the same group in the "Prerelease" tab.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug, and the same thing just happened to me.
I cannot say if this is an effective solution, but I found that you can get the minus button to display via a simple modification of the page in your browser. In Safari, go Develop > Show Web Inspector, click the Inspect button, click your build number in the Build section, and in the DOM editor remove the ng-hide class in the next link.

You can then click the red - button, then click the + button, and select your new build.

It seems to stick, but because you don't get the usual iTunes Connect email and notification and don't get asked the questions you usually see when submitting an update, I am very much unsure that this is an effective solution (and if it were, then this could be a loophole). Will update if I get more information.

**EDIT** The next day, the Reject Binary button had reappeared, and I was able to use it.

Comment: I just did the same thing and didn't get an email.  I'll check tomorrow to see if the button reappears.