# Cannot Delete App binary in ItunesConnect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, release

I had submitted an version 2.0 of my app for review recently.
It got rejected by apple for a valid reason.
I made the changes and tried to upload a new binary with the same version say 2.0
But it wont upload it via Xcode saying an binary with version 2.0 already exists.
I couldn't find any way to remove the 2.0 rejected build from the Pre-Release tab.
I tried this
[reject this binary in new itunes connect UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678723/reject-this-binary-in-new-itunes-connect-ui) .
  But this did not help either

Thanks in advance.
Cheers.

Comment: Change version number to `2.0.1`.

Comment: I know this works but this is pathetic.

Comment: No it isn't. You should never create two binaries with the same version number.

Comment: Update build number to 2.1.

For more info see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788342/how-to-developer-reject-an-app-in-itunesconnect-after-the-sep-2014-changes

Comment: How is it pathetic? Version `2.0` wasn't up to standard so you have to do a new build with new fixes so that is a perfectly valid reason for it to become version `2.0.1`. Have a read of software versioning http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete app Build in New iTunes Connect Site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683441/how-to-delete-app-build-in-new-itunes-connect-site)

Comment: Oftentimes the build on our end IS "up to standard" but due to Apple/XCode/iTunes Connect's constant and ever-morphing numbskullery we are forced to reupload a new version with no actual changes to our codebase just to satisfy their arbitrarily convoluted process.  It IS indeed pathetic to mess with our version numbers due to the failings of their own system.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't need to increase the *version* number. But increasing the *build* number should allow you to submit.

Note that this is in the "new" iTunes Connect. The idea being that you can have multiple versions being tested by different groups of people. The unused builds are removed when they expire (note that there's a date attached).

Comment: How to increase build number?

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the **version number** and **build number** then submit the binary

Comment: I know this works but this is pathetic. Shouldn't we be able to delete the binary and upload a new one instead. Kudos apple!!!

Comment: if you upload a new binary with 2.0 then is no way to distinguish that you uploaded a binary with 2.0 and it got rejected