# No Reject this binary link in the new iTunes Connect 10/09

Tags: ios, binary, app-store-connect

My app has been waiting for review for more than 8 hours now. I want to reject the current binary and submit a new binary but the "Reject this binary" link fails to appear. I tried to delete the browser cache, cookies but that dint help. Tried using firefox, safari and chrome with no success. Even the iTunes connect mobile app does not provide me the reject this binary button.

I found similar threads here like this one - [reject this binary in new itunes connect UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678723/reject-this-binary-in-new-itunes-connect-ui) but those people were able to reject their binaries through the mobile app unlike me.

Anyway knows how I can fix this?

This is what I see on my iTunes Connect page
[image]

Comment: Please post a screenshot of what you're seeing.

Comment: @rebello95 - Thanks! Added a screenshot to the main question.

Comment: that's very strange... I'm seeing the option in my iTunes Connect for a pending update. Do you just have that 1 app waiting for review?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Yes I have just one app waiting for review. I'm using safari. But also tried this in chrome and Firefox. The itunes connect mobile app does not give me a discard this binary option either :(

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you fixed it?

Comment: I contacted apple support and they fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

In the "Build" section of the page "Versions":

1. Right click on the current version
2. Inspect Element
3. Remove "ng-hide" from the class of the tag: `<a href="" class="deleteIcon ng-binding ng-hide" ng-show="versionInfo.preReleaseBuildVersionString.isEditable" ng-click="removeBuild()"></a>`
4. Click Remove
5. Select new build
6. Save

Seems like, the method removeBuild() has no any checking of the isEditable value.

Comment: Are you suggesting that they should edit the web page? Not sure that actually answers the OP question

Comment: These actions allows to remove/change current build after sending application to the review. I had the same problem and I just shared my solution :)